# Snapping polygons edges within the same shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, snapping

How can I snap polygons edges within the same shapefile? The objective is to get rid off blank spaces between polygons edges.

Comment: What software and version are you using?  Are you looking for an automated or manual method?  How many polygons are you looking at?

Comment: I am using Arcmap v10.2. I am looking at over a 100 polygons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use geodatabase topology if using ArcGIS.

Geodatabase topology provides an automated, rule-based solution for maintaining the spatial integrity of your GIS data.

In the topology create a rule not to allow gaps and fix the gaps. It is very fast.

Here is a video to get you started. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIDxUcG8op0

Use a feature dataset inside a file geodatabase to store your data and the topology.

Comment: Are you sure rules can be created for Map topologies?  I thought they could only be created for geodatabase topologies.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall. shoot. thanks the video and gap rule are correct but I said map the whole time....updated, darn terminology.